# JAVA Encrypt String twice with different keys and decrypt it

Tags: java, encryption

I would encrypt a string using AES Algorithm  twice using 2 differents keys . And after that , i want to decrypt the encrypted string with the same 2 keys using in encryption . 
I used this function and it works for one encryption and decryption but not for second encryption/decryption :

```html
 public String encryptDecryptAes(String key , String input , int mode) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException, ShortBufferException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        java.security.Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        String result = null;
        byte[] inputBytes = input.getBytes();
        byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes() ;

        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes , "AES") ;

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding", "BC");

        if(mode==0) {

            //Encrypt
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

             cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(inputBytes.length)];
             ctLength = cipher.update(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.length, cipherText, 0);
            ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);
            result = new  String(cipherText);


        }

        if(mode==1) {

            //DECRYPT
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            byte[] output = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(ctLength)];
            int ptLength = cipher.update(cipherText, 0, ctLength, output, 0);
            ptLength += cipher.doFinal(output, ptLength);
           result = new String(output);
        }

        return result ;
    }
```

Comment: Where did you stuck!!

Comment: I need doing double encryption with different keys .. is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing an encryption should be possible an unlimited number of times, as you are just starting with a plain text and finishing with a new cipher text. When decrypting you will need to make sure you use the keys in reverse order. The process would be similar to as follows:

Starting with a text called plainText.

Encryption:

- Encrypt plainText with key 1, store in singleEncryption
- Encypt singleEncryption with key 2, store in doubleEncryption

Decryption:

- Decrypt doubleEncryption with key 2, store in singleEncryption
- Decrypt singleEncryption with key 1, store in plainText

The use of variables in this example is to simplify the explanation, it is not required that you actually have more than one copy of the text.

EDIT: If you think of the keys used for encryption as being a stack, so the last in is the first out.